# find $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{|x-2|}{(x^2)-4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{|x-2|}{x^2-4}$$

in this question when i replace $x$ with $h$, such that $h\to0$ and check for RHL and LHL.I get the same values for both RHL and LHL.
what i do is $\lim_{h\to0}|2-h-2|/((2-h)^2-4) = 1/h$ for LHL
             $\lim_{h\to0}|2+h-2|/((2-h)^2-4) = 1/h$ for RHL

but when i plot the graph it comes out the there should not be a limiting value at x=2. how should i go about it ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how in your first statement you get $|2-h-2|$ in your numerator?  I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Hint: numerator does not go to 0, denominator does go to 0, $x^2-4$ is always negative for $x\to 2^-$, always positive for $x\to 2^+$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the expression does go to infinity as $x \rightarrow 2$, and you can see this from your work because $1/h$ blows up for small $h$.

So you did right.

By the way, in the problem as written the absolute value is a bit of a red herring; since $x$ is near 2, you could replace it with just $4-x$.
Your instructor probably meant to put $|x-2|$ in the numerator; that makes for a more interesting problem.

Comment: it was indeed $|x-2|$ in the numerator